# Does MySQL permit callbacks in C such that when a change happens, I can be notified?

Tags: mysql, c, callback

Does MySQL permit callbacks in C such that when a change happens in the database, like an insert, that is performed by a different program or by the user at the command line, I can be notified?

I am guessing that it doesn't, because mysqlclient is a library, not a running thread. But I may as well ask.

Answer (score 5):

Create a trigger like so.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER ad_mytable_each AFTER DELETE ON MyTable FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  #write code that trigger After delete (hence the "ad_" prefix)
  #For table MyTable (The _MyTable_ middle)
  #On each row that gets inserted (_each suffix)
  #
  #You can see the old delete values by accesing the "old" virtual table.
  INSERT INTO log VALUES (old.id, 'MyTable', old.field1, old.field2, now());

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

There are triggers for `INSERT`, `DELETE`, `UPDATE`
And they can fire `BEFORE` or `AFTER` the action.
The trigger `BEFORE` the action can cancel the action by forcing an error, like so.

```
CREATE TRIGGER bd_mytable_each BEFORE DELETE ON MyTable FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  #write code that trigger Before delete (hence the "db_" prefix)
  declare DoError Boolean; 

  SET DoError = 0;

  IF old.id = 1 THEN SET DoError = 1; END IF; 

  IF (DoError = 1) THEN SELECT * FROM Table_that_does_not_exist_to_force_error;
  #seriously this example is in the manual.

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

This will prevent deletion of record 1.

A before UPDATE Trigger can even change the values updated.

```
CREATE TRIGGER bu_mytable_each BEFORE UPDATE ON MyTable FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF new.text = 'Doon sucks' THEN SET new.text = 'Doon rules';
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Hope you'll be Trigger happy.

Comment: I wish I could give you an additional +1 for the @Doon reference in your code.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL's triggers allow you to hook into insert/update/delete queries and do something additional. You could log them in a separate table, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Well you could attach a trigger to user defined function, and have it call an external program, that would then notify your code..

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/faqs-triggers.html#qandaitem-B-5-1-10

Answer (score 1):

You can use [triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/triggers.html) combined with [UDFs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-functions.html) (user defined functions) so that the corresponding action on the database executes a trigger that calls a C/C++ function.

Just consider that this mechanism runs your code inside the mysql server process, not in the client side.