# MySql Notifications

Tags: java, mysql

Good day! 
I am developing an application that uses java and mysql as back end. My problem is, I want the application to be notified when changes to the database occurs, like an insert/delete/update to the record. I google this many times and found some answers like using JMS and others. I need some help how to obtain this functionality.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5668679/does-mysql-permit-callbacks-in-c-such-that-when-a-change-happens-i-can-be-notif

Comment: As is, your question is too broad.  SO is for solving specific problems, not end-to-end solutions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7220697/mysql-callback-is-there-such-a-thing

Answer (score 1):

User mysql trigger in your database.If you do not use trigger, learn [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html).